# Is it somehow possible to have more than one source file with Java's "Single-file mode"?

Tags: java, include, mode, single-file

I'm aware that this question sounds a bit absurd, but it would be sooo nice to `#include` source code that is shared among multiple Java-single-file scripts, e.g. like so:

`./scriptone.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/java --source 11

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Script #1");
        Util.printHello();
    }
}

#include util.java
```

`scripttwo.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/java --source 11

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Script #2");
        Util.printHello();
    }
}

#include util.java
```

`util.java`:

```
public class Util {
    public static void printHello() {
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$ ./scriptone.sh
Script #1
HELLO
$ ./scripttwo.sh
Script #2
HELLO
$
```

Instead, you get

```
$./scriptone.sh
.\scriptone.sh:10: error: illegal character: '#'
#include util.java
^
$
```

Unfortunately, Java's single-file mode does not support `--source-path` either, which would be a viable alternative to load and compile auxiliary classes.

Is there any "hack" to achieve what I want?

Comment: IMO the restrictions on single file mode were put there quite intentionally to avoid the temptation to do exactly what you're trying to do. Understand that your use case is not covered by the single-file mode and find another solution.

Comment: Maybe they relax that restriction in the future, like they did for other Java features, e.g. interface default methods. But in the meantime...

Comment: I don't think they should relax them. This would develop into a parallel universe of dependencies-between-source-files which is really not the kind of dependency-hell that I wish Java development gains.

Comment: Trying to repurpose a quick-and-dirty implementation into something more complex rarely ends well.

Comment: I don’t agree that this is a quick-and-dirty implementation (JEPs rarely are). I find the single-file mode and shebang feature super useful, and the only thing that is a real pain is the impossibility to have code that is shared between multiple related scripts in one place. IMHO there is no technical reason to not enable the `—source-path`.